# Keeping first div box and deleting rest based on search pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div data-attrType="time">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="inputBox">
            <div class="input-text-grp">
                <input name="startTime" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="inputBox">
            <div class="input-text-grp">
                <input name="startTime" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="inputBox">
            <div class="input-text-grp">
                <input name="startTime" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have the div stored in a Jquery variable `$x`. If I do `$x.find('.box')`, I will get the 3  boxes. What I am trying to do is keep only the first box and delete the remaining boxes and set the text in the first box as empty. So the resultant div structure should look something like this:

```
<div data-attrType="time">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="inputBox">
            <div class="input-text-grp">
                <input name="startTime" type="text" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using splice method, however, it isn't deleting the remaining boxes.

Comment: `$x.find('.box:not(:first)').remove()`. I'm sure you can figure out how to use `val()` to empty an input yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all the next `box` after the first one and remove those...

```
$x.find('.box:eq(0)').nextAll(".box").remove();
```

To reset the input value you can use

```
$x.find('.box:eq(0) input').val("");
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can solve that by using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):**

```js
var $x = $('.box');

$x.each(function(i, val) {
  if (i > 0) {
    $(this).remove();
    console.log('deleted '+ (i+1) + '. box');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-attrType="time">
  <div class="box">1.
    <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="input-text-grp">
        <input name="startTime" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">2.
    <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="input-text-grp">
        <input name="startTime" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">3.
    <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="input-text-grp">
        <input name="startTime" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```